# How to query fields with MySQL-Regex that contain thousand separator?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table that contains content with and without numbers. I need to find those entries with numbers.

Example:

```
We are going to examine 1.523 data points that were collected with 2.456.213 participants. 
Having an income of more than 1.000,20 Euros.
```

Each entry containg only one type of the numbers above should be found.

I tried without success:

```
SELECT * FROM `db_content` 
WHERE content REGEXP "\d{1,3}\\.\d{3}"
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `db_content` 
WHERE content REGEXP "\d{1,3}(.\d{3})*(\.\d+)"
```

but it always returns 0 entries.

What is wrong with the RegEx?

Comment: I would suggest using your source data and transform it into normalized rows of data.This new table would be able to be analyzed much faster than relying as the relatively slow REGEX. Write your own ETL tool if need be to do the hard work. 2.5 million records are not all that many but if you plan on growing that data set or doing something complex like cross table analysis then you should take care of reformatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support the `\d` regex capture group. You have to replace with one of the following:

- `[0-9]`
- `[[:digit:]]`

So your query can look like these:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `db_content` 
WHERE content REGEXP '[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{3}'

-- or 

SELECT * 
FROM `db_content` 
WHERE content REGEXP '[[:digit:]]{1,3}\\.[[:digit:]]{3}'
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=556bd6c2e89ab6bb3ea56a972bde822e)

Comment: I just realize that the `.` must be escaped! So `.` becomes `\\.` in the REGEXP. That was another pitfall. You can update your answer accordingly.

Comment: @KaiNoack - Yes that's right. I fxied that also on the answer, but the main problem was the `\d`.